# How to deny movement on some tiles in a tile-based javascript game?

Tags: javascript

I've created the map for the game already and now I'd like to deny movement on some tiles. For example some tiles are the path where the character moves and the other ones are forest, grass or something like that where the character can't move. Here's my code of the map:

```
var mapLeft = 224;
var mapTop = 160;
var protagonistLeft;
var protagonistTop;
var tileProperties = [
    [ true,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [true, true, true, true,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false,],
  ]
```

I was thinking of something like this but I don't know what to put instead of "deny movement" and "allow movement" :

```
if (tileProperties = true){
    allow movement  
}
else {
    deny movement
}
```

EDIT:

I'm not actually moving the player. The map behind it is moving and the player is always in the middle. But heres the code:

```
function positionSettings() {
    document.getElementById("gameWindow").scrollLeft = mapLeft;
    document.getElementById("gameWindow").scrollTop = mapTop;
    document.getElementById("protagonist").style.left ="507px";
    document.getElementById("protagonist").style.top ="347px";
}

function moveMap(keystroke){
    switch(keystroke.keyCode){
        case 37:
            mapLeft = mapLeft - 8;
            positionSettings();
            break
        case 38:
            mapTop = mapTop - 8;
            positionSettings();
            break
        case 39:
            mapLeft = mapLeft + 8;
            positionSettings();
            break
        case 40:
            mapTop = mapTop + 8;
            positionSettings();
            break
    }
}

function loadMap(){
    for(updown=0;updown<50;updown++){
        for(leftright=0;leftright<50;leftright++){
            //alert(tileProperties[leftright][updown]);
            var tile = document.createElement("div");
            tile.setAttribute("class","mapTile");
            if(tileProperties[leftright][updown]){
                tile.setAttribute("style","background-color:#00FF00;left:"+ leftright * 32 +"px; top:"+ updown * 32+"px;");
            }
            else{
                tile.setAttribute("style","background-color:#FFFF00;left:"+ leftright * 32 +"px; top:"+ updown * 32+"px;");
            }
            var tileNum = document.createTextNode(leftright +":"+ updown);
            tile.appendChild(tileNum);
            document.getElementById("worldMap").appendChild(tile);
        }
    }
    positionSettings();
}
```

EDIT:

This is my HTML code if it helps (there's also some style code but it's got nothing to do with movement so I won't post it here.):

```
<body onload="loadMap()" onkeydown="moveMap(event)">

    <div id="gameWindow">

        <div id="worldMap">
        </div>

    </div>
        <div id="protagonist">
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us your function "move"? (The one with wich you move the player). Basically: `if(tileProperties) {move();} else {alert('Nope');}`

Comment: I created a comment of my movement code down below.

Comment: In `moveMap`, check if the new position is valid. If so, use `loadMap` with the right coordinate, no need for else since the player will not move in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Something that is way easier to work with is using a char map... for example:

```
M = ["wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww",
     "w::::::::::::::::::::::::::::r::::::w",
     "w:::::::::::::t::::::t::::::r:::::::w",
     "w:::::::t:t:::::::t::::::::bbb::X:::w",
     "w::::::t::::::::::::::::::::r:::::::w",
     "E::*::::::t:::t:::::::::t:::r:::::::w",
     "w::::::::::::::::::::::::::::r::::::w",
     "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"];
```

where for example `t` means a tree, `b` means a bridge, `r` a river, `w` a wall, `*` the initial position for the player, `X` the treasure to grab, `E` the exit point (doors open only when you've got the treasure) and so on...

Then you can create a map for each flag and use it with:

```
var can_walk = {'b': true, ':': true, 'X':  true};

...

if (can_walk[M[y1][x1]]) {
    // Step ok, update coords
    x = x1; y = y1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made some time ago this "game" for fun. It's not complete and the code should be arranged in a better way but it should be useful for you:

JS

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("grid");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var tile = new Image();
var cursorImg = new Image();
cursorImg.src = "http://www.sebissimos.com/imgs/rmt_icon.png";
var game = function(document) {
    this.document = document;
    this.grid = {};
    this.cursor = {
        spriteImg: cursorImg,
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        cellx: 2,
        celly: 2
    };
    this.tile = function(idx, idy, x, y, type) {
        this.idx = idx;
        this.idy = idy;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.sprite = new Image();
        if (type === "dirt") {
            this.walkable = true;
            this.sprite.src = 'http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/tibia/images/0/0b/Dirt_%28Light%29.gif/revision/latest?cb=20091024213053&path-prefix=en';
        }
        if (type === "rock") {
            this.walkable = false;
            this.sprite.src = 'http://christessmer.com/sprites/tiles/grey_rock_tile.png';
        }
    };
    this.map = [
        ["rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "rock", "dirt", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "dirt", "rock", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "rock", "dirt", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "dirt", "rock", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "dirt", "rock"],
        ["rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock", "rock"]
    ];
    this.firstStart = true;
    this.initGrid();
};

game.prototype = {
    getInput: function(kc) {
        actualx = this.cursor.cellx;
        actualy = this.cursor.celly;
        if (kc == 37) {
            nextx = actualx - 1;
            if (this.grid.squares[actualy][nextx] != undefined && this.grid.squares[actualy][nextx].walkable)
                this.cursor.cellx = nextx;
        }
        if (kc == 38) {
            nexty = actualy - 1;
            if (this.grid.squares[nexty][actualx] != undefined && this.grid.squares[nexty][actualx].walkable)
                this.cursor.celly = nexty;
        }
        if (kc == 39) {
            nextx = actualx + 1;
            if (this.grid.squares[actualy][nextx] != undefined && this.grid.squares[actualy][nextx].walkable)
                this.cursor.cellx = nextx;
        }
        if (kc == 40) {
            nexty = actualy + 1;
            if (this.grid.squares[nexty][actualx] != undefined && this.grid.squares[nexty][actualx].walkable)
                this.cursor.celly = nexty;
        }
    },
    start: function() {
        game = this;
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            game.draw();
        }, 10);
        function checkKey(e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            game.getInput(e.keyCode);
        }

        document.onkeydown = checkKey;
    },
    draw: function() {
        if (this.firstStart) {
            this.grid.squares.forEach(function(yrow) {
                yrow.forEach(function(cell) {
                    context.drawImage(cell.sprite, cell.x, cell.y);
                });
            });
        }
        context.drawImage(this.cursor.spriteImg, this.grid.squares[this.cursor.celly][this.cursor.cellx].x, this.grid.squares[this.cursor.celly][this.cursor.cellx].y);
    },
    initGrid: function() {
        this.grid.squaresize = 32;
        this.grid.squares = [];
        var idx = 0;
        var idy = 0;
        var posx = 0;
        var posy = 0;
        for (var y = 0; y < this.map.length; y += 1) {
            this.grid.squares[y] = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < this.map[y].length; x += 1) {
                this.grid.squares[idy][idx] = new this.tile(idx, idy, posx, posy, this.map[y][x]);
                idx++;
                posx = this.grid.squaresize * idx;
            }
            idx = 0;
            posx = 0;
            idy++;
            posy = this.grid.squaresize * idy;
        }
    }
};
window.onload = function() {
    test1 = new game(document);
    test1.start();

};
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="grid" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/xqjp4j72/7/
Edit: now with maps.

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the new position is valid before moving. Else, does nothing and leave the player at his initial position.

```
function moveMap(keystroke){
    switch(keystroke.keyCode){
        case 37:
            if (isValidTile(mapLeft - 8, mapTop)) {
                mapLeft = mapLeft - 8;
                positionSettings();
            } else {
                //Do nothing, as if no keypress, to ignore it
            }
            break;
        case 38:
            if (isValidTile(mapLeft, mapTop - 8)) {
                mapTop = mapTop - 8;
                positionSettings();
            } else {
                //Do nothing, as if no keypress, to ignore it
            }
            break;
        case 39:
            if (isValidTile(mapLeft + 8, mapTop)) {
                mapLeft = mapLeft + 8;
                positionSettings();
            } else {
                //Do nothing, as if no keypress, to ignore it
            }
            break;
        case 40:
            if (isValidTile(mapLeft, mapTop + 8)) {
                mapTop = mapTop + 8;
                positionSettings();
            } else {
                //Do nothing, as if no keypress, to ignore it
            }
            break;
    }
}

function isValidTile(leftright, updown) {
    if(!tileProperties[leftright][updown]) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for some reason. Now it doesn't move at all.

Comment: Basic error from my part, `isValidTile` take two properties, and I only set one. Try again now. Also, you can upvote an answer to thanks the answerer (by clicking the up arrow at the left of the answer), and accept a answer by clicking the mark, to show that the answer work for you. You should consider doing that here and on your other question.

Comment: Should have looked your code more than a second. Your map is true for wall and false for ground. My code made the inverse assumption. Fixed. (Also, that was another simple error, did you study what I ve done or did you copy/pasted and called it done?)

Comment: My map is actually a lot bigger, I just made a smaller one to post it here. And the player should still move on the true tiles. I also wanted to ask what does the isValidTile exactly do?

Comment: `isValidTile` check if the player can walk on the tile he want to go, return true if he can, false if he can t. If he can walk, walk, if he can t, do nothing and ignore the keypress

Comment: Which part of the code ignores the keypress? And before you wrote that I have to use loadMap with the right coordinate. That's the     function isValidTile(leftright, updown) {
    if(!tileProperties[leftright][updown]) {
        return true;
    }  part, right?

Comment: You just don t do anything, there is no need for a "ignore" function, you just return to waiting for a keypress.